# Oracle Apex cookie expiration offset by 8 hours

Tags: oracle, cookies, timezone, oracle-apex

The cookies I create with [`owa_cookie.send`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/w_cook.htm#ARPLS387) are getting an additional 8 hours to the expiration date.

The server is using UTC time (The result of `select to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi') from dual` is the same as the current UTC time). So I don't think the difference is caused by the time zone.

I'm now using the following call to create a cookie (note the `-8/24` on the `expires`). It works for now, but this doesn't seem very safe.

```sql
-- creates a cookie that lasts for 1 hour that can also be seen by JS
-- the value of the cookie is the expiration date in ISO format
owa_cookie.send(
  name => 'TEST_DTM',
  value => to_char(cast((sysdate + 1/24) as timestamp) at time zone 'UTC', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3"Z"'),
  expires => sysdate + (1 - 8) / 24,
  path => '/ords',
  secure => 'Y',
  httponly => null);
```

Does anybody know where the difference in time is coming from?

Answer (score 1):

You have an implicit cast from a `TIMESTAMP` to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`:

```sql
to_char(
  cast((sysdate + 1/24) as timestamp) -- TIMESTAMP (without time zone)
  at time zone 'UTC',                 -- TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
  'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3"Z"'
)
```

This is effectively adding a time zone:

```sql
to_char(
  cast(sysdate + 1/24 as timestamp with local time zone)
  at time zone 'UTC',
  'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3"Z"'
)
```

Which converts `SYSDATE` in the database's time zone to the local time zone (whichever time zone the client application is using, and not the database time zone) and then converts it to UTC.

---

You would be better to use `SYSTIMESTAMP` rather than `SYSDATE` and save yourself a lot of confusion about data types and time zones:

```sql
TO_CHAR(
  (SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '1' HOUR) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
  'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"'
)
```

However, if you really did want to use `SYSDATE` then use the database time zone rather than the local (client) time zone:

```sql
to_char(
  FROM_TZ(CAST(sysdate + 1/24 AS TIMESTAMP), DBTIMEZONE)
  at time zone 'UTC',
  'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3"Z"'
)
```

---

For example, if the database time is UTC and you do:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai';

SELECT 'SYSDATE with implicit local cast' AS method,
       to_char(
         cast(sysdate + 1/24 as timestamp)
         at time zone 'UTC',
         'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3"Z"'
       ) AS utc_timestamp
FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SYSDATE with explicit local cast',
       to_char(
         cast(sysdate + 1/24 as timestamp with local time zone)
         at time zone 'UTC',
         'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3"Z"'
       )
FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SYSDATE with explicit DB timezone cast',
       to_char(
         FROM_TZ(CAST(sysdate + 1/24 AS TIMESTAMP), DBTIMEZONE)
         at time zone 'UTC',
         'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3"Z"'
       )
FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SYSTIMESTAMP',
       TO_CHAR(
         (SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '1' HOUR) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
         'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"'
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Then the output is:

> | METHOD | UTC_TIMESTAMP |
> | --- | --- |
> | SYSDATE with implicit local cast | 2021-11-01T04:07:04.000Z |
> | SYSDATE with explicit local cast | 2021-11-01T04:07:04.000Z |
> | SYSDATE with explicit DB timezone cast | 2021-11-01T12:07:04.000Z |
> | SYSTIMESTAMP | 2021-11-01T12:07:04.200Z |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=87ab4e78f564eddc1dba5a3259afa9cd)*

Comment: Thank you for your response, I changed the `value` and the `expires` parameters so that they use `SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '1' HOUR` instead of `sysdate + 1/24`, the value of the cookie is still good but the expiration is still off by 8 hours.

Comment: @nickzoum The documentation on `OWA_COOKIE.SEND` is unclear on what it expects (and if it will assume any time zone and apply any conversions to UTC) but you could try also passing `expires => (SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '1' HOUR) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',` and it will be implicitly cast back to the expected `DATE` data type.

Comment: I've already tried that, it's still off by 8. I requested a demo apex workspace so that the issue can be easily reproduced. URL: [https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/), workspace: `nzapptest`, username and password: `testtest`. The request is under SQL Workshop>RESTful Services>modules>test>expiration>get

Comment: @nickzoum I've tried a few bits but can't get it to the value you want; however, your assumption that "The server is using UTC time" is incorrect as `DBTIMEZONE` is `-05:00` (but that's still not 8 hours difference).

Comment: The query `select DBTIMEZONE from dual` returns `+00:00` on the server I'm working on (it's `-05:00` on the test server I requested so that the problem can be easily reproduced without sharing sensitive data). Does this mean the problem is most likely not related to the timezone but rather a fixed +8 hours added by the owa_cookie package or apex?